# The best image file format for TEXT and tools to make it

Tags: image, command-line

Need to convert pdf file to image file (jpg, png, gif) to show on the web. 
Exploring goole application to that reads PDF files shows that they are using PNG. But hov to onvert 2000x2000 file so it have only 150 kb? 
Is there any command line tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG and GIF are better than JPEG, GIF probably better than PNG. TIFF usually is the best.